# The intersection of maximal subgroups of abelian group is not trivial.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, maximal-subgroup

I want to find the sufficient and necessary condition of intersection of maximal subgroup of abelian group is not trivial.

I showed intersection of maximal subgroup of a group $G$ is normal subgroup of $G$. I know fundamental theorem of abelian group.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The fundamental theorem only applies to finitely generated abelian groups. In that case a necessary and sufficient condition is the existence of an element of order $p^2$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I prove that?

Comment: @bellow: Use the fundamental theorem; an element of order $p^2$ means a factor of the form $C_{p^n}$ with $n\gt 2$. Show every maximal subgroup includes at least the maximum subgroup of that factor.