# Frattini subgroup $Φ ( G )$ is not trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, frattini-subgroup

Frattini subgroup $Φ ( G )$ of a group G is the intersection of all maximal subgroups of $G$.
The question is

> Let $G$ be an abelian group.What is the sufficient and necessary condition of $Φ ( G ) ≠｛e｝$？

I think if $G$ has no torsion part, we cannot say $Φ ( G ) ≠｛e｝$,because $\Bbb Z ×\Bbb Z×・・・
×\Bbb Z$ has a maximal subgroup $p\Bbb Z ×\Bbb Z×・・・×\Bbb Z$, with intersectioning distinct primes, we gain just a trivial group.

So, we need torsion part. But I cannot proceed from here.I only know the answer, $G$ has an element of order $p^2$, that  is, $G$ has theree subgroups.
I want to deduce this consequence from steady discussion.

P.S
[The Frattini subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}_p \times\Bbb Z _{p^2}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533537/the-frattini-subgroup-of-bbbz-p-times-bbb-z-p2?rq=1)
According to this answer, in a ring that is a finite direct product of quotient rings of $\mathbf{Z}$, we can say rattini subgroup is the same as the Jacobson radical of the corresponding ring.

Comment: Use `$\Phi$` for $\Phi$, `$\times$` for $\times$, and `$\neq$` for $\neq$.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the Frattini subgroup consists of the "non-generators" of the group? (Elements which never occur in a minimal generating set of the group.) So prove that if $x$ has order $p^2$ then $x^p$ is a non-generator (which is manageable).

Comment: Note that if $A$ and $B$ are groups, then $\Phi(A\times B)\subseteq \Phi(A)\times\Phi(B)$: if $M$ is maximal in $A$, then $M\times B$ is maximal in $A\times B$, and similarly for $B$. Similar for a finite product. It should be easy to figure out $\Phi(\mathbb{Z}$ and $\Phi(\mathbb{Z}_{p^a})$ for primes $p$. That will give you an upper bound.

Comment: Why is this a different question from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3898785/the-intersection-of-maximal-subgroups-of-abelian-group-is-not-trivial) ?

Comment: As I said in a comment to your earlier post, we seem to be just talking about finitely generated abelian groups. I don't know what the answer is for abelian groups that are not finitely generated.